# how to get the checkbox on a card reflect the hilite status of another checkbox in the data grid

Tags: livecode

I'm a complete beginner so bear with me if this is very simple.
I have 2 cards in a stack (see link). Card 1 shows few text lines that can be selected with a checkbox an viewed by clicking on the 'My Selection' button.
Toggling selection of lines and switching between 'All Lines' view and 'My Selection' view works OK - the checkboxes get selected/diselected in a proper way.

When I click on the text line itself I go to a card 2 showing the whole text line. On that card I placed a checkbox to be able to toggle selection as well. That checkbox however is not showing the hilite status of the visible line properly and it does not dissellect the checkboxes in the data grid on the card 1.

For the checkbox on cd 2 I use this code for the card it is on:

```
global gMySelection,gMySelectedLineNrs,gCurrentLineNr,gCurrentLine,gCurentIndex

on openCard
   set itemDel to tab
   put gCurentIndex into fld "a" --- used during development
   put gCurrentLine into fld "b" --- used during development

   if gCurentIndex is among  items of gMySelectedLineNrs then
      set the hilite of btn "Check" to "true"
   else
      set the hilite of btn "Check" to "false"
   end if

end openCard
```

and for the check button on that card this:

```
global gAllLines,gMySelection,gMySelectedLineNrs,gCurentIndex

on mouseUp
   set the itemDelimiter to tab
 if the hilite of me then
  put "true" into item 2 of line gCurentIndex of gMySelection
  put "true" into item 2 of line gCurentIndex of gAllLines
   else 
      put "false" into item 2 of line gCurentIndex of gMySelection
      put "false" into item 2 of line gCurentIndex of gAllLines
   end if
   RefreshAllLines
end mouseUp
```

How to correct the code so that it works properly?

[download link for my stack](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/99863601/DG-checkbox%20selection2.zip)

Thanks in advance.

keram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working now.
This line was not correct: "gCurentIndex is among  items of gMySelectedLineNrs", because while gCurentIndex was always a simple number, gMySelectedLineNr were always with leading 0, so even though gCurentIndex could be = gMySelectedLineNr but could not be found among items of gMySelectedLineNr.